# Errors while trying to create list of points in a grid rectangle (beginner)

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++, and I'm trying to create a `Rect` class for grid rectangles, which is created using two vectors: the `start` point (top-left), and the `dimensions`. I would like to create a method for `Rect` called `get_points()` which returns a vector of all the grid points inside the rectangle.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <cstdlib>  //I will be using random numbers later
#include <vector>

class Rect {
    private:
        int* start, dimensions;
        int area;
    public:
        Rect(int[], int[]);
        ~Rect();
        std::vector <int> get_points(){
            std::vector <int> points(0);
            for (int i=0; i<area; i++) {
                int point[2] = {start[0]+i%*dimensions[0], start[1]+i/ *dimensions[0]};
                points.push_back(point);
            }
            return points;
        }
};

Rect::Rect(int* start, int* dimensions){
    this -> start = start;
    this -> dimensions = dimensions;
    this -> area = dimensions[0] * dimensions[1];
}

Rect::~Rect(){}
```

I am receiving the following errors:

```
||In member function 'std::vector<int> Rect::get_points()':|
|14|error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript|
|14|error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript|
|15|error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'std::vector<int>::value_type {aka int}' [-fpermissive]|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.    h|881|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void std::vector<_Tp,     _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc =     std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int]' [-    fpermissive]|
||In constructor 'Rect::Rect(int*, int*)':|
|25|error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
```

Out of all of these, I would most like to know what is causing the `invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript` error.

Comment: int* start, *dimensions

Comment: i am not a pro but you can not push array in a vector? T think you should do class point , conatructed with two ints, and use it in a vector

Answer (score 1):

```
int* start, dimensions;
```

Does not declare 2 pointers - it is one pointer and 1 int.

You want to do:

```
int *start, *dimensions;
```

You need to put one star for each variable. In such cases I prefer to keep the star on the variable's side, rather than the type, to make exactly this situation clear.

Also, you cannot push an array of ints in a vector of ints

```
points.push_back(point);
```

Finally,

```
i%*dimensions[0]
```

Should not have a `*`. nor should

```
i/ *dimensions[0]
```

Changing these things should fix your errors

Answer (score 1):

The first answer gets one problem however another is that you have extra

```
*
```

in front of dimensions in line 14.  It does not make sense even if dimensions is declared properly.  You need to remove those extra stars as well after fixing the declaration as specified above.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Vectors for your start and dimensions, you are using pointers to ints. Note that arrays of ints are not assignable to a Vector, as you attempt to do using push_back(). The assignment operator for Vector only works for Vector and initializer_list.

Why not just use ints for your x, y, width and height members? Your code becomes much simpler, and if you need to return them as Vectors to some caller, you can construct the Vector at that time. Or, if you need to return those vectors thousands of times, you can construct them in the Rect constructor.

Comment: You're right, I probably should just use integers - that would make everything much simpler. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I badly mis-read the code. Your push_back() is incorrect, but it's because you're trying to insert an array of ints into a Vector that's defined to contain ints.